# Laravel Query Builder For MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Please I need the laravel query builder equivalent for this mysql query:

```
SELECT * from shifts WHERE staffs LIKE (select CONCAT("%", id, "%") FROM users where email = 'turner.alexandra@gmail.com')
```

The above query

Comment: Tell us what you've tried so far, and someone will be able to help.

Comment: I assume `staffs` field is a string with delimited user IDs? This query is wrong then and will give you the wrong results. Searching for user 24 will give results for user 1024 as well which is probably not expected.

Comment: @ChrisCynarski yes

Comment: Using `LIKE` will force database to make full table scans for each query like this making the performance suffer. You have to create a lookup `shift_staff` table with shift_id, user_id columns. Than you can do the simple relation user->shifts on the Laravel model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the answer

```
//Get the id from user Table
  $users =  User::where('email', $email)->get();
  foreach($users  as $user)
  {
   $id = $user->id;
  } 
//Use The Id to Get the Result
  $availableShift = DB::table('shifts')
                    ->select('*')
                    ->where('staffs', 'LIKE', '%'.$id.'%')
                     ->paginate(2);
```